# Is there any power plug that passengers may use on the Buquebus boat service between Buenos Aires and Montevideo?

Tags: power, argentina, sea-travel, buenos-aires, montevideo

Is there any power plug that passengers may use on the Buquebus boat service between Buenos Aires and Montevideo?

Comment: I just browsed a couple of pictures on tripadvisor and I am actually surprised that most people are not dealing with their mobiles. I didn't see any power outlets close to the seats: https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attraction_Review-g294323-d3782437-Reviews-or15-Buquebus-Montevideo_Montevideo_Department.html#photos;aggregationId=101&albumid=101&filter=7&ff=372903353

Comment: There are some: https://www.tripadvisor.de/ShowUserReviews-g294323-d3782437-r487649869-Buquebus-Montevideo_Montevideo_Department.html#photos;aggregationId=101&albumid=101&filter=7&ff=258015843